# Change Sampling Rate in jPlayer

Tags: jplayer

How can I change the sampling rate of an audio played with jPlayer? I have this audio (WAV) recorded at 250 KHz and I want to play it at 44.1 KHz. I don't want to modify the audio itself, just play it "slower". If this is not possible with jPlayer, what is another option (library) to go with. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To play it 'slower' just set the `playbackRate` to less than 1.

http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-playbackRate